# mono asp.net System.Web.Compilation.ParseException the parent type does not derive from System.Web.UI.Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, mono

I have a WebForms application targeting 4.5.2. It is running fine in VS2015 and on IIS.

I want to deploy on mono on Ubuntu 18.04.

One of the pages, and just one, complains that the codeBehind class is not derived from System.Web.UI.Page, but I can assure you it is. It follows the same pattern of the other pages that do work.

I can see that no code is being generated for the aspx page (in the temporary dll that is created by the batch compilation process).

I also get a warning that the aspx file is skipped because of above error.

Again, it IS derived from System.Web.UI.Page. I did setup a complete monodevelop environment, and I get exacly the same error as with apache2/mod_mono, but I don't get any errors/warnings from monodevelop.

Any suggestions? Any suggestions how to debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a problem in the designer file. I figured this out by slowly commenting out items.

This particular page used an iframe and VS2015 declared an HtmlIframe for this. Mono(Develop) doesn't like this, and apparently doesn't know about an HtmlIframe. I still don't understand why there is no proper error message about this.

I replaced the HtmlIframe with an HtmlGenericControl, and everything is fine.